# Error: Please install mysql2 package manually when using pkg with Sequelize MySQL in Node.js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm trying to package my Node.js application, which uses Sequelize with MySQL, using pkg. However, I'm encountering the following error during runtime:

```
Error: Please install mysql2 package manually
at ConnectionManager._loadDialectModule (/snapshot/psq/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/abstract/connection-manager.js:55:15)
at new ConnectionManager (/snapshot/psq/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/connection-manager.js:30:21)
at new MysqlDialect (/snapshot/psq/node_modules/sequelize/lib/dialects/mysql/index.js:13:30)
at new Sequelize (/snapshot/psq/node_modules/sequelize/lib/sequelize.js:194:20)
at Object.<anonymous> (/snapshot/psq/dist/database/index.js)
at Module._compile (pkg/prelude/bootstrap.js:1926:22)
```

I tried all possible solutions like install npm install mysql2, npm install -g mysql2 ... etc, all of them is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is because Sequelize requires `mysql2` package (since you are using MySQL) during runtime.

Note that its during runtime, and not when you create your package (which is why your build passes).

There are few ways to solve this:

1. The clients who use your package need to provide `mysql2` in runtime environment
2. You can bundle `mysql2` into your package.

All packagers/bundlers will try to strip away as much as code as possible. That means, even if you had installed `mysql2` in your package, but haven't required it in your package, then it shall NOT be bundled.

So to solve it, in your sequelize configuration, just use `mysql2` like:

```
new Sequelize({
    ... sequelize options
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectModule: require('mysql2'),
})
```

That `require` statement will make sure `mysql2` is bundled inside your package.

---

If you are using ES Modules (ESM) instead, then use:

```
import mysql2 from 'mysql2'

new Sequelize({
    ... sequelize options
    dialect: 'mysql',
    dialectModule: mysql2,
})
```